# Google maps support of Internet Explorer 11 v3.47 after November 2022

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer

The last version of the Maps JavaScript API to support Internet Explorer 11 is v3.47. Support for Internet Explorer 11 will be entirely discontinued in November 2022.
I am trying to figure out what happens after November 2022? Will v3.47 still be available to work on IE 11?
We are integrated with Epic and some users will still be using IE browser until they switch entirely to chromium based browser.

Answer (score 0):

The official suggestion from Google is **encourage your users to switch to a [supported browser](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport)**.

For the user experience after November 2022, I think you can contact [Google Maps Platform Support Team](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/) for detailed information.

Reference link: https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/c/l3mdkZ5JyDg/m/Ml84u2nvBgAJ